# MySQL Triggers, summary each minute

Tags: mysql, triggers, summary

I have some data generated continously and i wonder how i could do something like that:
Each minute it will take x records from one minute before, make some kind of summary and put it in the second table.
Table looks like:
http://puu.sh/bvNA3/9616f1037f.png
Cols: ID, ID_pistol, ID_container, start_time, stop_time, volume, brutto, netto, temperature
in result for one minute it would be sum of volume, bruto, netto cols and average of temperature.

If anyone have some suggestion i would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Event Scheduler for this. Suppose `ID` in first table has `AUTO_INCREMENT` option. Then I suggest add to second table `last_id` column (to record last processed `ID` from first table). Then create event:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
  DO
    INSERT INTO second_table(volume_sum, bruto_sum, netto_sum, temperature_avg, last_id)
    SELECT SUM(f.volume), SUM(f.brutto), SUM(f.netto), AVG(f.temperature), MAX(f.ID)
      FROM first_table f
     WHERE f.ID > IFNULL((SELECT MAX(last_id) FROM second_table), 0);
```

This works only if Event Scheduler is started. User with admin privileges can check and start it. To check:

```
SHOW VARIABLES  like 'event_scheduler';
```

The answer must be `ON`. If it's `OFF` then run:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

*Documentation:*

- [Using the Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html)
- [Event Scheduler Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html)
- [CREATE EVENT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html)